# Is relative growth rate affects the accuracy of Malthusian Model on Certain Interval?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

So, namely i have $5$ models. And as we know the Malthusian model has form
$$\frac{dP}{dt} = kt$$
And the solution of the ODE above is
$$P(t) = ce^{kt}$$.
And the formula for Relative Growth Rate *(RGR)* from [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_growth_rate) is
$$RGR = \frac{\ln(P(t_2)) - \ln(P(t_1))}{t_2-t_1}$$
Where $t_2$ and $t_1$ represent the year of the population. E.g. $t_2=2021$ and $t_1=2000$. We know we need $2$ points to determine the solution of Malthusian model, and the informations $t_2$ and $t_1$ have contribution on this.

And as i said before, i have 5 models means i use different $t_2$ and $t_1$ as their initial conditions. And i realized that the smaller the RGR value, the more accurate it is (at least on the nearest interval, suppose $t_2=2021$ and $t_1=2000$, the nearest interval is between $1980$ and $2025$).  It is evident from the plot data I have drawn (I will upload if it's necessary).  Can anyone confirm this thought, or is this just a coincidence?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

In this edit section, i'd like to include the calculation of RGR and compare the results with the predicted data plot and the real (actual) data.

Here is my calculation of RGR on several models:

[image]

And the data plots:

$RGR=0.0195738$ :

[image]

$RGR=0.016577$

[image]

$RGR=0.0159$

[image]

For convenient reason, i only give 3 of them. And as you can see, the smaller RGR gives me better prediction on given interval (Might not accurate on another interval). Anyone can explain about this if this is just a conincidence or not? Thanks

Comment: Your question is hard to follow. I think you are saying that each pair of data points (you have five pairs) gives you a different value for $k$. It does not make sense to ask which value is the "most accurate". You could put all the data in a spreadsheet and ask it to calculate an "exponential trendline" (Excel's term). That will give you a value of $k$ that best fits the data. (If I have not interpreted your question correctly you will have to [edit] it to clarify.)

Comment: @EthanBolker Thanks for reply. As i said "the smaller the RGR value, the more accurate it is". $RGR\ne k$. Do you have a suggestion what should i add as a clarification detail?

Comment: @EthanBolker Please see my edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wikipedia formula for RGR is actually the calculation of the constant $k$ when you know two points on the exponential curve.

The fact that the fit happens to look best when you use any two particular points to find $k$ is a coincidence. The right way to find the "best" $k$ is to fit a linear regression line to the logarithmic plot of the data. Then $k$ is the slope of that line.

That's what Excel does when you ask it for an "exponential trendline". It's what you should do in this example.